# Is the GA User Activity API compatible with GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to retrieve user's data from a GA4 property using the User Activity API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting)?

I have checked the documentation but have not found anything so far. Some endpoints of the v4 API explicitly display a warning saying it is not compatible with GA4, but this User API does not display such warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no it is not as stated at the top of the page for the Reporting api [Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4)  there for it apply sto the full Reporting API v4.

> Note: This API does not support Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties. Please use the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) to access the new reporting features for GA4 properties.

As far as i can see there is no equivalent in GA4 yet.

Note: I pinged the team to have them add the quote to the top of that page as well.

Comment: Does it mean that so far there is no way to get the user id from `page_view` events using the GA4 API?